# Updating version in pom.xml (maven project)

Tags: maven, pom.xml, dependency-properties

My goal is to change version of a dependance , I modifiy the version in pom.xml  but when I check the effective pom , there are the two versions , in addition. 
I clean install maven where it download the new version and when I build it , the new version doesn't appear 
I can't unterstand why , help please.

Comment: Show your pom.xml...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effective pom is not a good place to understand the dependencies.

If you want to use a specific version of a dependency, either set this version in your dependencyManagement or add it to your dependencies. Then you can use `dependency:list` to check whether your version is indeed drawn. If not, have a look at `dependency:tree` to find out where the wrong entry comes from. If unsure about the result, post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the dependency is being injected from other jars. Also try deleting the old version from .m2/repository and then clean install it .

Comment: This method is applicable for certain dependency , but par exemple spring-cloud-starter-ribbon still download the 2 versions 1.3.0 and 1.3.5 what is wrong, because I have a vunlerability in spectator-api-0.30.0.jar , i should update the version